# FB meta image tag not working

Tags: facebook, image, url, post, meta

I have this meta tag for an image to pull when the link to an article is posted on FB:

```
`<meta property="og:image" content="http://crossfit954.com/photos/t-316.jpg"/>`
```

However its pulling 3 other images not including the t-316.jpg I need. Running it through
the FB debugger says  `Can't Download   Could not retrieve data from URL.`

I'm not sure what else I need to get that image to be the thumbnail that posts on FB when I paste the link, any thought?

Comment: just for the record `crossfit954.com/photos/` has no index file and can you put the link you're trying to debug? is it `crossfit954.com/photos/` or something else?

Comment: It was the whole link. The photo I wanted to use was in the "photos" directory and the image t-316.jpg was the image in that directory. I thought the og:image tag had to point to the image you wanted to use.

Comment: yeah you must point the `og:image` content to the image you want to use as thumbnail

Comment: So the full URL http://crossfit954.com/photos/t-316.jpg will not work as the thumbnail?

Comment: It will but where did you use it? it's kinda small

Comment: I used a larger image now `http://crossfit954.com/photos/316.jpg` and FB debugger says `Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px.` does it have to be square?

Comment: Can you put the url you're trying to debug?

Comment: http://www.crossfit954.com/success/23/ben-garcia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger has all errors you need!

[image]

Use a bigger image to show the thumbnail you want and add the reuqired [OGP tags](http://ogp.me)

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Example" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/example.jpg" />
```

Comment: You were right. The real error was the URL, I used the base URL of the site so in order to get it to point to the page I needed I used `http://<?=$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]?><?=$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?>` and wala! The right image appeared. Thanks